# Trying to insert all the information in the form to update in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

thanks for taking a look at this. I have been stuck at this problem for awhile basically i am doing a recruitment agency website for my school project. I am doing the function where i can view all the candidate who applied for any job and i can choose from the dropdown box whether to "approval", "denied", or remain as "pending" which it should update the table in the database to the option i chose and it will reflect at the candidate's page. However with the codes i am using right now, it is able to display all the information i need from the different table on the page but when i try to submit the details, it only works for the last guy that applied and not the rest.

This is the form :

```
<form method="post" action="doEditStatus.php">

<div align ="center">

<table border='1' width ="500">

<tr>

 <td> <b> ID </b></td>
            <td> <b> Candidate name </b></td>
            <td> <b> Job ID </b></td>
            <td> <b> Job title </b></td>
            <td> <b> Company </b></td>
            <td> <b> Shortlist status </b></td>
 </tr>

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $jobid = $row['Job_id'];
    $canid = $row['Candidate_id'];
 ?>  
 <tr>

<td><?php echo $canid; ?></td>

<input type="hidden" name="can_id" value=<?php echo $canid ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="job_id" value=<?php echo $jobid ?>>
<?php

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE Candidate_id =$canid";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $canname = $row2['First_name']." ".$row2['Last_name'];
?>

<td><?php echo  $canname; ?></td>


<?php
}

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE Job_id =$jobid";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {

    $jobname = $row3['Job_title'];
    $comid = $row3['Company_id'];
    ?>

    <td><?php echo  $jobid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $jobname; ?></td>        
    <?php
}

$query4 = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE Company_id =$comid";
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {

    $comname = $row4['Company_name'];
    ?>

    <td><?php echo  $comname; ?></td>

    <?php
    }

?>

<td>
     <select id="id_status" name="shortlist_status">
     <option value="0">Pending...</option>
     <option value="1">Shortlist</option>
     <option value="2">Denied</option>
     </select>

     </td>

 </tr>

<?php

}

?>

</table>

</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


</form>
```

This is the dosubmit page:

```
<?php
include "dbFunctions.php";

session_start();

$candidate_id = $_POST['can_id'];
$job_id = $_POST['job_id'];
$status = $_POST['shortlist_status'];


$insertQuery = "UPDATE application SET Shortlist_status = '$status' WHERE Candidate_id = $candidate_id AND Job_id = $job_id";

$inserted = mysqli_query($link, $insertQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));

if($inserted)
{
    $message = 'Profile edited successfully <br><a href="testing.php">Home</a>';;
    echo $candidate_id;
    echo $status;
}
else
{
    $message = "Profile edited failed";
}
echo $message;

?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You're right.. think i will look into that once i am able to complete the function first. Thanks for the headup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all your inputs names that end with `[]`. PHP will then create an array for each of them in `$_POST`. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="can_id[]" value=<?php echo $canid ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="job_id[]" value=<?php echo $jobid ?>>
```

Then your PHP can do:

```
$insertQuery = "UPDATE application SET Shortlist_status = ? WHERE Candidate_id = ? AND Job_id = ?";
$insertStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $insertQuery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertStmt, "iii", $status, $candidate_id, $job_id);
foreach ($_POST['can_id'] as $i => $candidate_id) {
    $job_id = $_POST['job_id'][$i];
    $status = $_POST['shortlist_status'][$i];
    $inserted = mysqli_execute($insertStmt) or die(mysqli_error($insertStmt));
    if ($inserted) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to input the codes you provided but i got this error "Notice: Array to string conversion on line 11
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'" Line 11 is $insertQuery = "UPDATE application SET Shortlist_status = '$status' WHERE Candidate_id = $candidate_id AND Job_id = $job_id";"

Comment: Sounds like you left out `[$i]` in the assignments.

Comment: I've added more code to show the whole structure, also changed it to use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgotten the [$i]. But now instead i got 
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1  on line 8

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2  on line 8

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3  on line 8

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4  on line 8

Comment: This is what i updated : foreach ($_POST['can_id'] as $i => $candidate_id) {
$job_id = $_POST['job_id'][$i];
$status = $_POST['shortlist_status'][$i];

$insertQuery = "UPDATE application SET Shortlist_status = '$status' WHERE Candidate_id = $candidate_id AND Job_id = $job_id";
$inserted = mysqli_query($link, $insertQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}        Is it at the right place?

Comment: It's the error i mentioned Uninitialized string offset:on line 8 :(

Comment: Did you add `name="shortlist_status[]"`? You need to change ALL the inputs to use this syntax.

Comment: Lol that's it! That was the problem! It worked now thanks man!